# How to prevent graphics remove from panel onPaint?

Tags: c#, graphics2d

I have a Canvas class who is Panel-inherited class that overrides the `onPaint` method.

My program looks like this:

[image]

It works good and all, but when I minimize \ resize the Canvas,

the "hidden" part of the canvas is deleting. I've noticed that I have to override the onPaint method.

But I don't know what to do to "keep" the draw. any suggestion?

Comment: are you sure that it's deleting or is it just not refreshing properly

Comment: Well, You should redraw the content to the window when is form resized. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @MatoKormuth I was explicitly required to override onPaint only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing something that happens when you use `CreateGraphics`.  Don't use `CreateGraphics`, but use the graphic object from the PaintEventArgs parameter, specifically `e.Graphics`.

Comment: @user1798362 That's not very helpful without seeing the code you are running in the paint method.  You don't dispose the `e.Graphics` object by the way, since you didn't create the object.